# RestKit: Map single object into existing array

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, core-data, restkit

I have the following JSON structure which i get from a RestService:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id": "123456",
        [more attributes ....]
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "1234",
            },
            {
                "id": "2345",
            }
            [more items...]
        ]
    }
}
```

which i successfully map into Core Data using RestKit. From another RestService (which i can not change) i then get more details to one single item in the items array. the JSON answer looks like

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id: "123456",
        "item": {
            "id": "1234",
            "name": "foo",
            [other attributes...]
        }
    }
}
```

Now the question: How can i map the second answer, so that the single item is added to the items array (or updated if it is already in there)?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to map JSON to Core Data, all that's left is just fetch theobject you want to add your item attributes to(using id or something else) and then just set it,rewriting the old one,or adding new fields.That's just general approach

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the second answer is recognized as a customer as well (due to the enclosing customer tag). So it maps the answer to a customer. As customer has no mapping for a "item" tag (only "items") it skips that tag. I would like to tell the mapper, that if a "item" tag appears, it should parse it into the "items" array. Of course i could fetch it manually, but i am looking for a more scalable solution if possible...

Answer (score 0):

If you set the appropriate `primaryKeyAttribute` of the `RKManagedObjectMapping` object you should be able to perform the mapping as you want it to. 
It would actually be easier to help you, if you would post some of your mapping code, but this is how I meant it to be

1. Create the mapping for your customer object, defining all possible attributes and declare the `mappingObject.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id"`
2. Execute the mapping with the first request (or first answer as you put it)
3. After the first mapping step is finished execute the second request

This should initially create the customer objects you want and then update them.